# Migrate to Azure Active Directory

Tags: cloud

We intend to migrate all our on-premises Active Directory accounts and resources to Azure AD. Then follow by migrating files and printers as well as on-premises applications, i.e. SQL onto the cloud. Eventually decommission on-premises AD.

Can someone please shed some lights on is there an Microsoft article outline steps on migration on-premises AD accounts to Azure AD?

Once we migrated all AD account to Azure, how do we go about migrating files and prints server to the cloud?

How does local PC connect to the account on the cloud?

Comment: As per the ServerFault guidelines, "Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2):

Please do read up on what Azure Active Directory actually is. It is not the same as Active Directory and does not present the same set of features. If you want traditional Active Directory in the Cloud.. That means running your own Domain Controller on Azure/Amazon/Something else.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. My understanding for Azure AD is that we are able to set up any VM on the clouds, i.e. AD (as per traditional AD) on Azure's VM. Then local user/PC can establish connection to i through a stable VPN connection. Hence this will allow for retiring of local AD. Trying to get more understanding on Azure as unable to find relevant article detailing this.

Comment: You are not describing Azure AD. You are describing running a VM with a domain controller on Azure and establishing a VPN from Azure to your on-premise network. This is of course possible.